# Select query on information_schema is too slow

Tags: mysql, performance, information-schema

```
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS 
WHERE CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = DATABASE() 
  AND CONSTRAINT_NAME   = 'FK_FOLDER_FILTER_CONTRACT_CATEGORY_CONTRACT_CATEGORY' 
  AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE   = 'FOREIGN KEY';
```

The above query takes around 2 mins to execute 
is there any other alternate query or how can we optimize this query

Comment: `information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS` is a view. Get its text, insert into your query, then simplify it by removing unnesessary parts. For example, it contains UNION which seems to be excess in your case (and a half of a query), you do not need to execute access rights checking function calls, and so on.

Comment: Which version of MySQL?  There was a huge change starting with 8.0.  Also, how many tables in your dataset?

Answer (score 1):

For grins, I `EXPLAINed` your query on 5.7:

```
+----+-------------+-------------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table             | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                                               |
+----+-------------+-------------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | TABLE_CONSTRAINTS | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | NULL |     NULL | Using where; Open_full_table; Scanned all databases |
+----+-------------+-------------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

And 8.0:

```
+----+--------------+--------------+------------+--------+--------------------+-------------+---------+---------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type  | table        | partitions | type   | possible_keys      | key         | key_len | ref                 | rows | filtered | Extra                                              |
+----+--------------+--------------+------------+--------+--------------------+-------------+---------+---------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY      | <derived2>   | NULL       | ref    | <auto_key0>        | <auto_key0> | 424     | const,const,const   |   10 |   100.00 | NULL                                               |
|  2 | DERIVED      | cat          | NULL       | index  | PRIMARY            | name        | 194     | NULL                |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                                        |
|  2 | DERIVED      | idx          | NULL       | ALL    | table_id           | NULL        | NULL    | NULL                |  244 |    40.00 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
|  2 | DERIVED      | tbl          | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,schema_id  | PRIMARY     | 8       | mysql.idx.table_id  |    1 |   100.00 | Using where                                        |
|  2 | DERIVED      | sch          | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,catalog_id | PRIMARY     | 8       | mysql.tbl.schema_id |    1 |   100.00 | Using where                                        |
|  3 | UNION        | cat          | NULL       | index  | PRIMARY            | name        | 194     | NULL                |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                                        |
|  3 | UNION        | fk           | NULL       | index  | table_id           | table_id    | 202     | NULL                |   63 |   100.00 | Using index; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
|  3 | UNION        | tbl          | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,schema_id  | PRIMARY     | 8       | mysql.fk.table_id   |    1 |   100.00 | Using where                                        |
|  3 | UNION        | sch          | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,catalog_id | PRIMARY     | 8       | mysql.tbl.schema_id |    1 |   100.00 | Using where                                        |
|  4 | UNION        | cc           | NULL       | ALL    | table_id           | NULL        | NULL    | NULL                |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                                               |
|  4 | UNION        | cat          | NULL       | index  | PRIMARY            | name        | 194     | NULL                |    1 |   100.00 | Using index; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
|  4 | UNION        | tbl          | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,schema_id  | PRIMARY     | 8       | mysql.cc.table_id   |    1 |   100.00 | Using where                                        |
|  4 | UNION        | sch          | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,catalog_id | PRIMARY     | 8       | mysql.tbl.schema_id |    1 |   100.00 | Using where                                        |
| NULL | UNION RESULT | <union2,3,4> | NULL       | ALL    | NULL               | NULL        | NULL    | NULL                | NULL |     NULL | Using temporary                                    |
+----+--------------+--------------+------------+--------+--------------------+-------------+---------+---------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
14 rows in set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)
```

The old code needs to open all the tables, so it is slow if you have lots of tables.

The 8.0 code fetches from InnoDB tables, but goes through lots of hoops.

The number of tables is not the same, so I could not make a valid comparison, not do I know how many tables you have.

Answer (score 0):

information_schema isn't a real database. To preform this query it needs to open tables.

The internal code for information_schema isn't optimized and it will frequently generate the data for the entire table requested without consideration of the query. As such your query could be opening every table regardless of the current table.

Comment: Your answer applies to versions before 8.0.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reduce my SELECT query against INFORMATION_SCHEMA from 12s to 0.001s by adding `AND TABLE_SCHEMA='DB_NAME'` to the query, on MySQL 5.6.

Before (12s):

```
SELECT
  AVG_ROW_LENGTH
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'myTableName';
```

After (0.001s):

```
SELECT
  AVG_ROW_LENGTH
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'myTableName'
  AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'myDbname';
```

Answer (score 0):

Using information_schema.statistics instead of information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS get better results

Explain TABLE_CONSTRAINTS without TABLE_NAME
Using where; Open_full_table; Scanned all databases

Explain TABLE_CONSTRAINTS with TABLE_NAME
Using where; Open_full_table; Scanned 1 database

Explain STATISTICS without TABLE_NAME
Open_full_table; Scanned 1 database

Explain STATISTICS with TABLE_NAME
Open_full_table; Scanned 0 databases

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).